# Inserting popup images in QGIS

Tags: qgis, popup

I want to make a presentation of a museum using QGIS. I have already designed the room layout in AutoCAD and inserted it in QGIS.

Now I want to insert the images in certain boxes (museum exhibits) so when I click on them it will pop up the image.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe using `Display` vector layer properties by configuring html code and it will display the exhibits by hovering the feature ? ([link to the doc](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#display-properties))

Comment: surely a duplicate ...

Answer (score 1):

An option you can consider is using the "Actions" feature. This document from QGIS provides a good example to use.

https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html

> The school_property layer has no way to associate an image with a property yet. First we’ll create a field for this purpose.
>
> Open the Layer Properties dialog.
> Click on the Fields tab.
> Toggle editing mode:

[image]

> add a new column

[image]

Once those details are setup,

> Click on the browse button (the ... next to the image field).
> Select the path for your image. The images are in exercise_data/school_property_photos/ and are named the same as the features they should be associated with.
> Click OK.
> Associate all of the images with the correct features using this method.
> Save your edits and exit edit mode.

[image]